# IntelliJ - Show errors/warning on the left of code

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I use IntelliJ after moving from Eclipse (With Java)
I like that errors/warnings are displayed on the code map on the right but I miss the indications of errors and warning that appear next to the problem on the left (gutter)

Is there a way to turn it on?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no indicator on the left side, but if you look at the right side there is an indicator near the lines the error was found (it's pretty vague though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible but you can hit F2 to cycle through the errors quickly.

Comment: Tnx. After I clicked F2 and arrived at an error, how do I see what it is with the keyboard?

Comment: ok, i get it, it shows on the status bar below.
Kinda annoying but okay.

Comment: ctrl+F1 gives you a nice popup :) (although you can naturally rebind it to something more handy, the name of the action is `Error Description`)

Comment: Wrote my comment a second before yours. That's better. Thanks!

Comment: No worries Ben! Another nice tip is to move the `7: Structure` pane from the lower left side to the lower right side (like where it is in Eclipse). This gives you more room for the `1: Project` pane, which is where you want to scroll up and down the most.